# referencing external javascript file

Tags: javascript

I want to store array value in an external javascript file and then use an internal script to write a loope that lists the values of the array stored in the external file. 
my javascript file is:

```
var Arr = new Array("one", "two", "three")
```

My internal script

```
<script src="test.js" datatype "text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
for (x in Arr)
{
document.write("<br />"+ Arr[x]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, it's not pretty, but it will "work". You should use a normal `for` loop though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for. Also read about arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however it would be tidier to fetch those values with AJAX and not use `document.write`. Also, that `datatype "text/javascript"` thing should be `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Good point regarding the HTML error... however I don't think that AJAX has to be mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

test.js Arr variable in function ??

sample: test.js

```
(function() {

    var Arr = new Array("one", "two", "three");
});
```

or

```
function fn() {

    var Arr = new Array("one", "two", "three");
};
```

then html file:

```
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    console.log(Arr); // Undefined Results
</script>
```

---

else sample: test.js

```
var Arr = new Array("one", "two", "three");
```

html file:

```
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    console.log(Arr); // ["one", "two", "three"]
</script>
```

---